# Mapping SqlDataReader result to object

Tags: c#, reflection, sqldatareader

I'm trying to create a generic method that will convert results from a `SqlDataReader` into a `POCO object` based on the property names. This is what I got so far:

POCO object:

```
public class Order
{
    [DbField]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    [DbField]
    public string OrderName { get; set; }
    [DbField]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    public int NonDbProperty { get; set; }
}
```

attribute definition:

```
public class DbFieldAttribute : Attribute { }
```

method to retrieve all property with the DbField attribute of an object:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertiesWithDbAttribute<T>()
{
    var allProps = typeof(T).GetProperties();
    var props = allProps.Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(DbFieldAttribute))).Select(n => n.Name);
        return props.ToList();
}
```

and the actual `SELECT` operation:

```
public object GetFirstOrder()
    {
        try
        {
            Order temp = new Order();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnection()))
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Order] WHERE OrderId = 1";

                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sdr.HasRows)
                    {
                        var props = Utils.GetPropertiesWithDbAttribute<Order>();
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {

                            foreach (string item in props)
                            {
                                temp.GetType().GetProperty(item).SetValue(temp, sdr[item]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return temp;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

this works in the tests that I've made so far, however I wonder if the automatic conversion between the `object` retrieved in `sdr[item]` is enough or should I use an explicit conversion based on the type of the property, for example:

```
//DateTime? property:
temp.GetType().GetProperty(item).SetValue(temp, sdr[item] == DBNull.Value? null: (DateTime?)sdr[item]);
```

Comment: Just an idea, but instead of reinventing the wheel, you could use LINQ to SQL or [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net).

Comment: This may be better suited to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @stakx I've been using EF in my other projects but in my current project I have to use this approach

Comment: User is not Dapper but stakx ;)

Comment: [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) is a micro-ORM, a very small library (830 lines) that offers ORM features. Essentially, it maps the results of a parameterized SQL string to objects using reflection. Discovered mappings are cached after the first use so you don't pay the reflection cost on each call. There's no reason to write your own code.